# getting info webscraping with bs within span tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch info from within a span tag with a value.

```
<td class="subtableheader">Status</td>
  <td class="profilerow"><span id="status" value="Levend (Offline for 0H 1M)">Levend (Offline for <abbr title="02-01-2022 22:53:24">0H 1M</abbr>)</span>
  </td>
```

I want to get the info:

```
Levend (Offline for <abbr title="02-01-2022 22:53:24">0H 1M</abbr>)
```

This is dynamic and can change (offline for 2 minutes, etc.) I have tried to fetch the info with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get_text(strip=True) == 'Levend')
```

But the response i am getting empty. I tried it this way because "Levend" is always there.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the tag you are searching contains more text than just "Levend". So using `tag == "Levend"` will never return True.

This code works:

`data = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and 'Levend' in tag.get_text(strip=True))`

Comment: still tells me the message it retrieves and tries to display is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The `span` could found by its id (`soup.find(id='status')`). Inner parts of this element are accessible with the `contents` property (I assigned them to the `nodes` variable). nodes items are tags so converting to string is required by `[str(node) for node in nodes]` and finally join the strings.

```
nodes = soup.find(id='status').contents
texts = ''.join([str(node) for node in nodes])
print(texts)
```

Comment: i've tried adding your code, instead of the one I made, it get this error now:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: do you use BeautifulSoup4? before this line I only had this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: yes, from bs4 import BeautifulSoup.

Comment: please comment this line `texts = ''.join([str(node) for node in nodes])` and then print `nodes` variable. and tell me the result. It runs without error for me.

Comment: is there an option to send the complete code of my project here somewhere? Because I think i've done something else wrong. And your code actually works.

Comment: use google cloud: https://cloud.google.com/python

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/discordbotpydataretrieving

i think this should work. The idea behind this is, someone needs to do a command, the script starts working and logs to the website, than goes to the correct webpage, retrieves data and displays data.

Comment: I think I told you the wrong address. https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: My code is here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16TLx7c-U_325pVKDX_ujH-S5ppNZMPMp?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, i've put my code underneath it. I think something else is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Assumes the html from your answer is in your soup - If not sure print(soup) and take a look.*

To select your element that should contain a string in `BeautifulSoup 4` you can use `css selectors` and grab the `.contents`.

Following example will search for tag with `id="status"` that contains the string  `Levend` and `join()` its `contents` via list comprehension as string.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<td class="subtableheader">Status</td>
  <td class="profilerow"><span id="status" value="Levend (Offline for 0H 1M)">Levend (Offline for <abbr title="02-01-2022 22:53:24">0H 1M</abbr>)</span>
</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print("".join([str(x) for x in soup.select_one('#status:-soup-contains("Levend")').contents]))
```

#### Output

```
Levend (Offline for <abbr title="02-01-2022 22:53:24">0H 1M</abbr>)
```